# Dynamic SQL INSERT

Tags: php, postgresql, select, dynamic

I have a PHP form which have many fields. What I want is to dynamicaly add fields to a query which inserts values in a PostgreSQL table, depending on the content of these fields. If a field (eg date, int, etc) is empty, I do not want it in the query because it causes a "syntax error" when I'm trying to INSERT to the table as it awaits for a value to insert. Help, please!

Edit

```
INSERT INTO hcd_customermeters ("meterSN", "contractCode",
                "deviceManufacturer", "deviceType",
                "firstInstallationDate", "diameter",
                "pipeID", "operatorCreator", "warehouseDeliveryDate",
                "recordCreation", "SRID") 
            VALUES ($1, $2, $3, $4, $5, $6, $7, $8, $9, $10, $11)'
```

Comment: Sounds like your query has - well incorrect syntax.
What have you done so far? You should show the code/query you're building for people to be able to help.

Comment: possible duplicate of [dynamic SQL insert query](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10944989/dynamic-sql-insert-query)

Comment: tailor, I checked that link but I don't think it's the same. That guy adds fields to the table, not the query. Allan the query I have so far is correct. Just a simple INSERT. I want to have a single save button, but all the fields must have values. If not, a syntax error occurs as I explained.

Comment: Please describe your problem with example. Your have already created table plz mention.

Comment: Edited. The table is ready and with records in it. My problem is when I try to insert a new record. The above query (in PHP that's why $) runs correctly. If there is no value for, let's say, pipeID in the corresponding field, the error occurs.

Answer (score 3):

In your mysql query define variable name incorrect change name :

Rules for PHP variables:

```
1) variable starts with the $ sign, followed by the name of the variable
2) variable name must start with a letter or the underscore character
3) **variable name cannot start with a number**
4) variable name can only contain alpha-numeric characters and underscores (A-z, 0-9, and _ )
Variable names are case sensitive ($y and $Y are two different variables)



$sql_insert = 'INSERT INTO hcd_customermeters ("meterSN", "contractCode", "deviceManufacturer", "deviceType", "firstInstallationDate", "diameter", "pipeID", "operatorCreator", "warehouseDeliveryDate", "recordCreation", "SRID") 
            VALUES ("'.$variableName."', "'.$variableName."', "'.$variableName."',"'.$variableName."', "'.$variableName."', "'.$variableName."', "'.$variableName."', "'.$variableName."', "'.$variableName."', "'.$variableName."',"'.$variableName."')';


mysql_query($sql_insert);
```

if any problem plz mention.

Comment: As I explained the query works fine. It's a prepared statement, so no need for escaping or quoting and the values are from an array. $params = array(...); That's not where my problem is.